# laravel 9 with cpanel database not connected

Tags: database, cpanel, laravel-9, access-denied

> QueryException
> PHP 8.1.10
> 9.34.0
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ctsgbcom_cchnorth'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

I am facing an issue in cpanel The hosting is Hostbreak.
I have tried to fix :
using double for password and usersname in .env
clear cache

but not resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain the user has access over the db?

Comment: check the password for user `ctsgbcom_cchnorth`

Comment: no everything is fine this issue has just come in only one hosting. the same project deployed into another website it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

This issue has just come in only one hosting. the same project deployed into another hosting and domain works fine.

I contacted support and ask him for the scenario of this issue than support asked me for the public IP of my and added my IP to our firewall.

Just contact support for your hosting.

Thanks